# join two aliases in apache pig based on a condition

Tags: join, apache-pig

I want to join two aliases/relations,

```
say A has keys : a,b,c
and B has keys : x,y,z
```

so it should be:

`C = JOIN A by a, (IF B.x matches "foo.*" then pick y else z)`

As in above logic.How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Answer:

Just generate a key based on the condition,then join by that key

eg.

```
BB = foreach B generate x,y,z,(x matches "foo.*") ? y : z as matchkey;
C = join A by a, BB by matchkey;
dump c;
```